# How can i use another stream data inside the Main Stream using flink

Tags: apache-flink

I have Employee Master data coming as the data stream NIFI connector, also have a KAFA Data Main Stream which contains employee details. Within the Process element, I have to use this Master data stream for doing some calculations. Is there any way we can do it.

My Current Design contains a Data Stream and a broadcast stream(broadCastStream) all the data processing is doing under process element in (mainDataProcessor) which is derived from KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction.
I am connecting my broadcast stream to main stream as mentioned below.
ie. mainStream.connect(broadCastStream).process(new mainDataProcessor())

Now we have an additional need to introduce one more Data Stream which contains a Master data coming from Casandra table with Help OF NIFI COnnector. I need this master table data steam inside the process element to do some calculations with main stream data and broadcast data, is there any way for that.

Answer (score 1):

What you usually want to do is to join the streams on a particular column. For example, using a [temporal join](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/joins.html#join-with-a-temporal-table-function).

If you are on DataStream, you can also use a join but you need to be careful with the state size (when can you discard data?).

If you don't have an employee id over which to join, you could also try to use [broadcasts](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/joins.html#join-with-a-temporal-table-function), but that's less recommended.

If you need more specific pointers, please update your question and also mention which API you are using.

Comment: I have updated the question. please let me know your comments.

Comment: Can you please add why joins are not applicable? I'd discourage to implement join-like things manually unless explicitly needed.

Comment: The master data stream and the main data stream and broadcast data all these three Stream data don't have a common structure, this will be used only for some calculations. That is why I am not using joins here.

Comment: Is it possible to use multiple broadcast stream along with Main Data Stream?

Comment: A [join|https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Sample_tables] is usually done between relations having different structure. Broad casts need to replicate the data across all computation nodes and should be only used when joins cannot work.